# How to load category using url_key and parent catgory_id?

Tags: category, catalog

How to get category using `url_key` and parent `category_id`?
If category structure is as follows

```
-Root
  --Mobile
    ---Android
    ---Windows
    ---iOs
  --Tablet
    ---Android
    ---Windows
    ---iOs
```

Then using following code if try to load `iOs` category using `url_key` it load always load root->Mobile->iOS

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->loadByAttribute('url_key', 'cat_urlkey');
```

How I can modify code so that, sub category load by `url_key` and respective parent `category_id`?

Answer (score 3):

You can load the attributes collection and get it's first element:

```
$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categories->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'cat_urlkey');
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => '1/15/%');
```

The second condition tells to take subcategories of the category with id 15.